# Forces on spring, Newtons third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

I'm trying to understand how Newton's third law works with springs.

If we hang a block on an ideal spring mounted to the ceiling, in equilibrium, the block is affected by gravity downwards and the spring force upwards. So according to Newton's third law the spring itself is affected by the spring force downwards. This makes sense in my brain, but what would be the force upwards, since the spring is also in equilibrium, right? Is this the reaction force to the gravitational force on the block? That wouldn't work if the block was accelerating e.g. downwards, since then the spring would be accelerating upwards which is not what's happening? There also has to be some force from the spring on the ceiling, does the reaction force to that just always cancel out the reaction force to the spring force so the spring stays in rest? But shouldn't that force depend on the weight of the block somehow?

Answer (score 1):

There is a force on the block due to gravity and a force on the block due to the spring. These are *not* newton's third law force pairs, but they do happen to cancel out since the block is moving at a fixed velocity (zero).

There is a force on the spring due to the block (a newton's third law force pair to the force on the block due to the spring) and a force on the spring due to the ceiling (or whatever the spring in attached to at the top).

There is a force on the ceiling due to the spring (a newton's third law force pair to the force on the spring due to the ceiling) and a force on the ceiling due to the walls.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m_s$ be the mass of the spring, $m_b$ the mass of the block and $g$ the gravitational acceleration.

The ceiling is pulled down by a force equal to $(m_s + m_b)g$.  It doesn't matter to the ceiling that the spring is a spring or whether it's stretched or not.  The ceiling feels the total weight of all the masses hanging on it.

The spring is pulled upward by the ceiling with force $(m_s + m_b)g$.  It is also pulled downward by two forces 1) $m_s g$ which is its own weight and 2)$m_b g$ which is the weight of the block.  So the spring also experiences a total downward force of $m_s g + m_b g$.  The total forces on the spring is zero because the upward force from the ceiling cancels the sum of both downward forces.

The block feels an upward force of $m_b g$ from the spring and a downward force of $m_b g$ from gravity.  The force on the block is also balanced to zero.

The downward force on the ceiling is also balanced by an upward force on its supports connected to the floor.

The only part the spring's ability to stretch plays is that the spring is stretched to a length equal to $m_b g / k$ where $k$ is the spring constant.  Why?  Because the spring's own gravity acts on the spring's center of mass and doesn't stretch it.  Only the block's weight stretches the spring.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the system which contains the mass, the ideal spring and the Earth (to which the spring is attached in some way).

There are three Newton third law pairs of forces and for each pair the magnitudes are the same and the directions are opposite.

- Contact force on bottom of spring due to mass and contact force on
  mass due to bottom of spring.
- Contact force on top of spring due to attachment to Earth and contact
  force on attachment to Earth due to top of spring.
- Gravitational force on spring due to Earth and gravitational force on
  Earth due to spring.

Note that the forces which are Newton third law pairs are always of the same type, eg contact, gravitational, electrostatic, etc, and act on different bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the system which contains the mass, the ideal spring and the Earth (to which the spring is attached in some way).

There are three Newton third law pairs of forces and for each pair the magnitudes are the same and the directions are opposite.

- Contact force on bottom of spring due to mass and contact force on
  mass due to bottom of spring.
- Contact force on top of spring due to attachment to Earth and contact
  force on attachment to Earth due to top of spring.
- Gravitational force on spring due to Earth and gravitational force on
  Earth due to spring.

Note that the forces which are Newton third law pairs are always of the same type, eg contact, gravitational, electrostatic, etc, and act on different bodies.

In your example if everything is at rest, ie has not net force acting, then the magnitudes of all the forces are the same.